# How to translate a query with an EntityState and a value from Entity Framework 5 to 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I'm migrating a system from Entity Framework 5 to 6 and I have the following query:

```
item.Count(x => x.ID < 0 && ((EntityObject)x).EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Added)
```

The item represents a value from IGrouping between an ID and an Entity. I have tested multiple solutions like:

```
context.ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityX>().Count(x => x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added);
```

However, as you can see, it misses one important value, the ID. This situation creates a more challenging situation because in other cases, I'm checking the ID in similar circumstances too.

I cannot find how to combine them both since they are required to complete the full migration. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my current solution:

```
//Get entity to filter:
var entity = EntityX.ToList().Where(x => x.ID < 0);

//Get current values    
var entity_values = context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues;

//Filter using ChangeTracker from the context
int total = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityX_Type>().Count(x => x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added && x.CurrentValues == entity_values);
```

Maybe anyone else knows a better solution.